# my code in android studio (i think it is in (toString))

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio

I have a problem in my code in android studio, I created it to say "Hello" when the person "abc" writes but that didn't work . can u plz help me. here is my codes

```
final Button butt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.butt);

butt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
          final EditText frag =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.frag);
final TextView hello=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello);
      String verb =frag.getText().toString();
if (verb=="abc"){
            hello.setText("Hello");
```

Comment: verb.equals ("abc")

Comment: please edit your code. it is unreadable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the condition in `if` block returns `false`
Use this code instead.

```
final Button butt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butt);

butt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       final EditText frag = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.frag); 
       final TextView hello = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello); 
       String verb = frag.getText().toString();
       if ("abc".equals(verb)) {
           hello.setText("Hello");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u so much . it works

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing string, always use .equals method

Example:

```
String str1 = "yourstring1";
String str2 = "yourstring2";

if(str1.equals(str2))//return false
{...}
```